# Flexible height for the whole page and divs

Tags: css

i used many ways to make a flexible height to the divs and the whole page but no way .

what i want to do is :

i have 2 columns in the page after the header (right_side , left_side)
the both left and right sides will contain flexible content .

so i need the height of the both columns be flexible.
also want the right side height depends on the left side because maybe the article will be taller than the right content ..

i tried "height" and "min-height" but no way

this is my code

```
<html style="min-height: 100%;">

<body style="min-height: 100%; width: 980px; border-right: 2px solid black;  
  border-left: 1px solid black; margin: 0 auto;">

    <div><img src="header.jpg"/></div>

    <div id="content" style="min-height: 100%">
    <div id="right" style="background: red; float:right; width: 280px;  min-height: 100%;">my flexible right content</div>
    <div id="left" style="background: blue; float:left; width: 700px; min-height: 100%;">
    <p>my flexible article </p>
    <p>my flexible article </p>

   </div>
  </div>

  </body>


</html>
```

Comment: If you want them to resize dynamically together, then you'll need to put either right div in the left or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/mcfarljw/erdH7/

You're going to need to use some divs in divs to get the effect of having one column flexible with another if you want it pure CSS and HTML. You can do something like this for the html format.

```
<div id="container2">
    <div id="container1">
        <div id="col1">
        </div>
        <div id="col2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd highly recommend you move your CSS styling into the head using references to the divs or put them in a seperated linked CSS file altogether.

Based on: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-2-column.htm

Comment: i tried everything 

finally i got the best way to do this using Jquery

get the height of the left col then give it to another element 

    $(window).load(function(){
    var left_height=$("#left").height();
      $("#right").css("height",left_height);
    });

Comment: Enforcing it with js is certainly another way to do it. I felt that you were looking for a css html only solution though. I'd still recommend looking at the examples and trying to clean up the html though. If you use jQuery too much to fix little layout problems, then code tends to get very messy.